# how to recover an amazon ec2 instance with a messed up sshd configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, sshd

when changing /etc/sshd_config I made a mistake and didn't notice that sshd wasn't running anymore when I logged out. Naturally I can not log back in because sshd is not running.

Is there any other way to connect back into a amazon ec2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an EBS back AMI, you can stop the instance, attach and mount the current volume to another instance, edit the config.

If it's an S3 based, launch a replacement instance.